# Getting repeated values inside dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am having a dropdown which is fetching values from json but as my json file having some repeated values so I want them only once ..before it was working fine as I was able to filter the values but when I included some more code it started again taking repeated values ..please have alook..Thank you..
`$(document).ready(function() {`

Variable usednames is filtering the values..

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "data.json,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(obj) {
        var jsObject = obj;
        var usedNames = [];

        $('<option>', {
            text: 'Select your Option',
            value: '',
            selected: 'selected',
            disabled: 'disabled'
        }).appendTo('#dropdown1');

        $('<option>', {
            text: 'Select your List Option',
            value: '',
            selected: 'selected',
            disabled: 'disabled'
        }).appendTo('#checkbox');





        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                usedNames.push(value.name);
            }
            /*  $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
            */

            $.each(usedNames, function(index, value) {
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['name'],
                    value: index
                }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
            });

        /*    $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your List Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            }).appendTo('#listbox');
            */



            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                $('#checkbox').empty();

                $('<option>', {
                  text: 'Select your List Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled'
                }).appendTo('#checkbox');

                var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                    if (value['name'] === selection) {
                        $('<option>', {
                            text: value['attr001'],
                            value: 'attr001'
                        }).appendTo('#checkbox');
                        $('<option>', {
                            text: value['attr002'],
                            value: 'attr002'
                        }).appendTo('#checkbox');
                        $('<option>', {
                            text: value['attr003'],
                            value: 'attr003'
                        }).appendTo('#checkbox');
```

My HTML file

```
  <form name="myform" id="myForm">

    <select id="dropdown1"></select>
     <!--  <select id="listbox"></select> -->
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see why. You have this code :

```
            if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                usedNames.push(value.name);
            }
```

Which works (or should work) just fine. But after that, you have this :

```
            $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['name'],
                    value: index
                }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
            });
```

By having a look at your code, it seems that `jsObject` is equal to `obj`. So, in the first part, you're indeed checking for repeated values, that you put in the array named `usedNames`.

But shortly after, you're appending `jsObject` to `#dropdown1`, so you're never using the array `usedNames`, which should only have unique values.

You should use `usedNames` after creating it, and forget about `obj` or `jsObject`, unless it caries some more information.

EDIT : Note that, when creating `usedNames`, you're also appending to your dropdown. So you're appending what will be the content of `usedNames`, and then appending `jsObject`.

Comment: Thank a lot ..worked now...bUt as I after ATTRIBUTE 1 in my dropdown i m getting watermarks of *SELECT YOUR OPTION* then after that my second value is coming why those watermarks are appearing of SELECT YOUR OPTION

Comment: @siya You are appending this line just after creating `usedNames`. So for each object of `obj`, you're appending "SELECT YOUR OPTION". You should append this line before your `each` function.

Comment: Yeah solved now ..Just one more thing why In my second dropdown why I am getting values 3 times again and again as I scroll there is some space then again values start coming

Comment: @siya I don't exactly see where this bug is, but I think it's from your last `each` function. For each item in `jsObject`, you're appending all of `jsObject` in `#listbox`. Try to delete this `each` function, or put it outside of your main `each`... Something like that.

Comment: OK..Thanks for ur suggestion .But I was wondering I used list box but my second values are coming inside a dropdown as I included only 1 dropdown in my page

Comment: @siya You used a <select> tag, so it's a dropdown. If you want to make a list of checkboxes (as I understand it), you should create a `<input type="checkbox">` or `<input type="radio">`, and append the same thing dynamically.

Comment: Sorry to ask again..But i included check box but nothing is shown inside in checkbox now...

Comment: @siya Please, try to search a little on Internet :) If I understand your problem, what you're trying to do is create a list of checkboxes depending on informations of the selected element of the dropdown. What you should do is check the selected element of the dropdown and add a `<input type="checkbox">` for each information of that element. If you're going to submit which checkboxes are checked, don't forget `name`and `value` attributes in your `input`. You can find how to do it by yourself now, I think :)

Answer (score 2):

You could fill a list of unique values before assigning it to the dropdown.

```
function unique(arr) {
var u = {}, a = [];
for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i){
    if(!u.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
        a.push(arr[i]);
        u[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
}
return a;
```

}

[Most elegant way to create a list of unique items in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688692/most-elegant-way-to-create-a-list-of-unique-items-in-javascript)