# Iterating through list creating new unique list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I know that some would mark this is a duplicate, but in my case (and my limited knowledge) i still haven't found any similar example which i can relate to.. 
Therefore i say sorry upfront :)

It's pretty straight forward for an experienced JS dev i assume..

I just cannot figure out how to match on a arrays property :

```
 if (!uniqueEnts.includes(ent.entity)) {  // how do i match on uniqueEnts.entityName ?
```

Current approach results in too many hits in the new list, and the check (look above) doesn't provide with the correct check against uniqueEnts.entityName

**JSON Input :**
[image]

**Desired output :**
new list (uniqueEntities) with the following two properties

- entityName (unique)
- entityColor (randomly generated)

**Code :**

```
 uniqueEntities() {
        let uniqueEnts = []
        this.nluDataUnfiltered.forEach(function (i) {
            i.entities.forEach(function (ent) {
                if (!uniqueEnts.includes(ent.entity)) {
                    let obj = {
                        entityName: ent.entity,
                        entityColor: Util.getRandomColor()
                    }
                    uniqueEnts.push(obj)
                    obj = null
                }
            })
        })
        return _uniqueEnts.entityName.sort().value()
        // earlier tryout --> return _(uniq(uniqueEnts.entityName)).sort().value()
    },
```

**UPDATED WITH LATEST TRYOUT :**

```
uniqueEntities() {
        let uniqueEntityObj
        var uniqueEntity = Array.from(new Set( data.map(el => this.nluDataUnfiltered.entities[0].entity) ));
            uniqueEntityObj = uniqueEntity.map(el => { 
                entityName:el,  
                entityColor: Util.getRandomColor() 
            });
        return uniqueEntityObj
    },
```

**Error :**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to create a list of unique items in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688692/most-elegant-way-to-create-a-list-of-unique-items-in-javascript)

Comment: Please update the question with the input, expected output and issue with the approach you have taken.

Comment: coming right away...

Comment: About your error in `map`: [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object/28770578)

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are checking if the `uniqueEnts` `array` includes the `string` contained in `ent.entity`, but `uniqueEnts` is an `array` of `objects`, it doesn't contain any `string`. So, for this reason, you got duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps could be to get all the unique entity from your array. I am doing this using sets as sets can only store unique values. And then using `.map` again to convert it to array of objects.

```
var setDataRaw = this.nluDataUnfiltered.map(
  (el) => {
    if (el.entities.length == 0)
      return [];

    return el.entities.map(
      (_entity) => {
        return _entity.entity;
      }
    )
  });

var setData = [].concat.apply([], setDataRaw);
var uniqueEntity = Array.from(new Set(setData));

var uniqueEntityObj = uniqueEntity.map((el) => {
  return {
    entityName: el,
    entityColor: Util.getRandomColor()
  };
});
```

Comment: updated the question with your approach, and error message.. Care to take a look ? (bm : entityName and entityColor is _not_ part of the input data..

Comment: @TerjeNygård see the updated answer. Your `Util.getRandomColor()` works fine right?

Comment: You can change the property names to whatever required.

Comment: getRandomColor works yes..  looking through updated answer.. *sec*.

Comment: seems like my head is struggling with data.map .. should it be : var uniqueEntity = Array.from(new Set( this.nluDataUnfiltered.map(el => this.nluDataUnfiltered.entities[0].entity) ));

Comment: Not exactly but yea mine had a little issue. See the updated answer! Lets see if this works. Debugging a non working snippet gets really tough :(

Comment: getting an evaluation error on this unfortunately :) Care to give me a second in chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165439/discussion-between-void-and-terje-nygard).

Comment: Big kudos and digital beer for @void!.. Thanks a lot for the time-consuming, and great help !

Comment: +1 for a nice solution using `Sets`. Just an observation, I think that the condition checking if the length of the `array` is `0` could be removed. If the
 `array` is empty the `map` method should return an empty `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Following the same @void's idea of creating an `Array` of unique entities from a `Set`, here you have his same code but using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the full `Array` of entities.

```
let uniqueEntityObj = Array.from(
    new Set(
        nluDataUnfiltered.reduce(
            (a, o) => (
                [...a, ...(o.entities.map(so => so.entity))]
            ),
            []
        )
    )
).map(p => ( {entityName: p, entityColor: Util.getRandomColor()} ));
```

Here you have the compact (and less readable) version:

```
let uniqueEntityObj = Array.from(new Set(nluDataUnfiltered.reduce((a, o) => ([...a, ...(o.entities.map(so => so.entity))]), []))).map(p => ({entityName: p, entityColor: Util.getRandomColor() }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your add @ElChiniNet :) Just a question of curiousity... how on _earth_ have you learned this ? :)

Comment: @TerjeNygård, it is no hard to learn. You can start [here](http://es6-features.org/). Anyway, my solution is more [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) but more [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). Your solution is OK and less complex, you just needed to change [some things](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/xcmkvs8k/).